# Problema con objetos en hilos de java

Tags: java

Estoy practicando los hilos y después de llevar un rato con ello no consigo llegar al punto donde en el método **run()** dentro de la clase **Requerimiento_1.java** reconozca los objetos de tipo **ArrayList()**, ¿debería crear los objetos dentro del método **run()**? aprecio cualquier sugerencia os pego por orden de aparición la clase main  **Main_Actividad01.java** y su clase correspondiente **Requerimiento_1.java** lo que pide la actividad es sacar la lista de los números primos y los no primos usando una hilo para cada una.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main_Actividad01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<Integer> lista_primos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Requerimiento_1 lista_primos1 =  new Requerimiento_1(lista_primos);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(lista_primos1);
    t1.setName(" Hilo 1 ");
    
    ArrayList<Integer> lista_Noprimos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Requerimiento_1 lista_Noprimos1 = new Requerimiento_1(lista_Noprimos);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(lista_Noprimos1);
    t2.setName(" Hilo 2 ");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    System.out.println("Esta es la lista de primos "+lista_primos + " esta en la lista de los No primos"+ lista_Noprimos);
    }
}
```

public class Requerimiento_1 implements Runnable{
private ArrayList lista;

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public Requerimiento_1() {
    super();
}
public Requerimiento_1(ArrayList<Integer> lista) {
    super();
    this.lista = lista;
}
public ArrayList<Integer> getLista() {
    return lista;
}
public void setLista(ArrayList<Integer> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}
public void add(ArrayList<Integer> req) {
    this.lista =  req;
}
public synchronized ArrayList<Integer> esprimo(ArrayList<Integer> lista_Noprimos, ArrayList<Integer> lista_primos) {
    int num;
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println("Dame un numero: ");
        num = sc.nextInt();
        // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no
        // es primo
        if (num == 0 || num == 1 || num == 4) 
            lista_Noprimos.add(num);
        System.out.println();
    for (int x = 2; x < num / 2; x++) {
            // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no
            // es primo
            if (num % x == 0)
                lista_Noprimos.add(num);
            //sino, es primo 
            else {
                lista_primos.add(num);
            }
              
          }
    }
    
    return lista;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Arrancando hilo: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);

        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println("El hilo ha terminado");
        }
}
```

Lo que no termino de tener claro es como arrancar el método **run()** utilizando los objetos creados en el método main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que entender es que todo lo que esté en hilos se puede ejecutar en cualquier momento, y el hecho de ponerle synchronized equivale a crear un cuello de botella que no es realmente lo que quieres en este caso para los cálculos pero sí para la lectura de datos.

Primero abstraemos la funcionalidad de pedir números y regresar una lista, perderemos un poco de desempeño la verdad, pero ganaremos que tu código sea más reutilizable y más fácil de mantener.

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions488069;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeerNumeros {

    
    public List<Integer> lee(Scanner sc) {
        int num;
        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Dame un numero: " + i + ":");
            num = sc.nextInt();
            lista.add(num);
            System.out.println();
        }
        return lista;
    }

}
```

Ahora los hilos los usaremos para procesar en paralelo los primos y los no primos por lo que renombraremos tu clase como `ExtractorDePrimos`:

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions488069;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ExtractorDePrimos implements Runnable {

    final List<Integer> lista;

    public ExtractorDePrimos(List<Integer> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    public void esprimo() {

        ArrayList<Integer> lista_Noprimos = new ArrayList<>(4);
        ArrayList<Integer> lista_primos = new ArrayList<>(4);

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            int num = lista.get(i);

            for (int x = 2; x < num / 2; x++) {
                // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no
                // es primo
                if (num % x == 0) {
                    lista_Noprimos.add(num);
                    break;
                } //sino, es primo 
                else {
                    lista_primos.add(num);
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println("Esta es la lista de primos " + lista_primos + " esta en la lista de los No primos" + lista_Noprimos + " del hilo " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Arrancando hilo: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        esprimo();

        System.out.println("El hilo ha terminado");
    }
}
```

Como verás reuso muchas de tus ideas como que:

- cada hilo puede crearse con la lista de números con los que va a trabajar
- cada hilo dice su nombre cuando inicia a correr

Finalmente la clase principal para llamar a todo queda como

```
package es.stackoverflow.com.questions488069;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main_Actividad01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> lista_primos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> lista_Noprimos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ExtractorDePrimos lista_primos1 = new ExtractorDePrimos(new LeerNumeros().lee(sc));
        Thread t1 = new Thread(lista_primos1, " Hilo 1 ");
        ExtractorDePrimos lista_Noprimos1 = new ExtractorDePrimos(new LeerNumeros().lee(sc));
        sc.close();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(lista_Noprimos1, " Hilo 2 ");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
```

Es importante que sepas que los hilos no neesariamente terminan en el óden en que los creaste, (y de hecho por eso imprimo su nombre junto con los resultados)  por lo que podrías obtener una salida como la siguiente.

```
Dame un numero: 0:
13

Dame un numero: 1:
53

Dame un numero: 2:
42

Dame un numero: 3:
31

Dame un numero: 0:
33

Dame un numero: 1:
57

Dame un numero: 2:
75

Dame un numero: 3:
23

Arrancando hilo:  Hilo 1 
Arrancando hilo:  Hilo 2 
Esta es la lista de primos [33, 57, 75, 23] esta en la lista de los No primos[] del hilo Hilo 2 
El hilo ha terminado
Esta es la lista de primos [13, 53, 31] esta en la lista de los No primos[42] del hilo Hilo 1 
El hilo ha terminado
```

En esta corrida si te fijas los cálculos se han hecho de manera independiente, y el hilo 2 acabó antes que el uno.

Si bien tu ejemplo funciona, el código es muy educativo y parece escrito en tiempos de tus abuelitos, desde el ya obsoleto java 8 se agregaron nuevos APIs que nos permiten hacer ese código menos en el paradigma orientado a objetos y un poco más en el paradigma funcional.

como el orden realmente no te importa, se puede hacer el cálculo de esprimo tamién de manera paralela con el uso del Stream API de la siguente manera:

```
lista.stream().parallel().forEach(num->{
        for (int x = 2; x < num / 2; x++) {
            // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no
            // es primo
            if (num % x == 0) {
                lista_Noprimos.add(num);
                break;
            } //sino, es primo 
            else {
                lista_primos.add(num);
                break;
            }

        }
    });
```

nota que `.parallel()` solito se encarga de crear tantos `Threads` como sea posible según las limitaciones de tu sistema para el código que le pases.

la llamada a `forEach()` es equivalente a un *for mejorado*, que internamente usa un iterador en vez de índices para recorrer la lista, y el parámetro que recibe es ni más ni menos que una *función lambda*, que como podrás intuir nos permite reducir mucho el código que se habría hecho en una clase interna anónima.

El código ya se ve mejorcito, pero sigue con muchos pasos para ser educativo, y estamos reservando en memoria un arreglo con el tamaño de 4 enteros por cada lista. Lo podemos modificar para usar colectores y que solito de manera paralela clasifique los números

```
public void esprimo() {

    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> primosyNoPrimos = lista.stream().parallel().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(num -> {
        for (int x = 2; x < num / 2; x++) {
            // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no
            // es primo
            return num % x != 0; //sino, es primo

        }
        System.err.println("El número no es positivo, no se trata de un primo a menos que se trate de Optimus Prime xD");
        return false;
    }));

    System.out.println("Esta es la lista de primos " + primosyNoPrimos.get(true) + " esta en la lista de los No primos " + primosyNoPrimos.get(false) + " del hilo " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Ahora suponiendo que sea un fanático del paradigma funcional podrías reducir tu método a:

```
public void esprimo() {

    Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> primosyNoPrimos = lista
            .stream()
            .parallel()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.partitioningBy(num -> IntStream.range(2, num / 2)
                    .mapToObj(x -> num % x != 0)
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(false))
            );

    System.out.println("Esta es la lista de primos " + primosyNoPrimos.get(true) + " esta en la lista de los No primos " + primosyNoPrimos.get(false) + " del hilo " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Que aunque está acomodado muy bonito tiene solamente dos líneas.
Para entenderlo solo toca observar que IntStream es un Stream pero optimizado para datos de tipos int, y que el método range trata de generar números en una secuencia del valor inicial al valor final, después simplemente nos da si para el índice dado el número en cuestion es primo o no, y al encadenar el método `findFirst`, el A´PIinternamente optimiza las llamadas para que no tengamos que generar todo el rango que especificamos inicialmente para el `IntStream`, sino solamente hasta que se cumpla la condición.
Lo último a destacar es que find first nos regresa una *semi-mónada* llamada `Optional`, que aunque si no la sabes usar puedes generar *NPE* (no, no se lee <strike>nepe</strike>, así se le conoce coloquialmente al NullPointerException), también cuando se usa de forma inteligente como acá nos da valores para los casos no contemplados, es decir, para los casos en que no se haya marcado como primo por el cálculo se encarga de marcarlo como no primo, y con eso te ahorras lidiar con los tipos de números no tan comunes como los imaginarios, los negativos, y demás condiciones raras que te pudieran sacar del espacio Z<sup>+</sup> (léase este enunciado final de manera rimbombante).

Hace tiempo también me cree algún artículo sobre como generar series a partir de algún subconjunto como en este caso lo es el de los primos, y que puedes hallar en mi sitio con explicación de algunas cosas más acerca del [uso de lambdas para hacer generadores](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/expresion-lambda-en-java-para-hacer-generadores/).